# How to retrieve the lsf queue parameter from an xterm

Tags: xterm, lsf

Let's say I have launched tons of xterm in different queues. Now they all clutter my screen and I have lost which one is which. I want to stick the LSF job-ID and the requested machine memory resource into the xterm header bar. (I know I can do that at startup but lets assume I have all these xterms already sitting on my desktop and I want to stick the headers in after the fact)

I can use this to put text into the xterm header:

```
echo -e "\033]2; You can rent this place for a commercial. \007"
```

I am thinking of something like this:

```
get name out of uname -n 
get machine resources for name out of bjobs <<== I don't know how to do that!!!
stick interesting stuff into header
run this in all my xterm.
```

Important stuff I want to get out of bjobs is :

- machine size (so I know which size jobs I can launch in that xterm)
- LSF job ID so that I know how to kill it.

Example how I launch an xterm:

```
qsub -q o_cpu_128G -J Gerts -P gf104 -n 8 -m "rel57" -R "span[hosts=1]" xterm -sb
```

Stuff I get out of bjobs

```
bjobs
JOBID   USER    STAT  QUEUE      FROM_HOST   EXEC_HOST   JOB_NAME   SUBMIT_TIME
8510290 ggottsc RUN   o_cpu      sc-xterm-02 8*sc-sim-21 Gerts     Mar  5 14:44
7347117 ggottsc RUN   o_cpu      sc-xterm-02 8*l-sim-156 Gerts     Mar 10 11:48
9081323 ggottsc RUN   o_cpu      sc-xterm-02 8*l-sim-237 Gerts     Mar 11 10:21
```

Thanks,
Gert

Answer (score 0):

I assume your 'qsub' command is a wrapper around bsub that submits the job interactively?

If so, for the jobId, you should be able to look at the environment variable $LSB_JOBID in your xterm to get it.  So you can run something like:

```
echo -e "\033]2; Job ID: $LSB_JOBID \007"
```

To get the current terminal's job ID into the title.

For "machine size", I'm unclear what you mean.  It sounds like you're interested in the memory of the machine, but you can get this from a lot of places.  Based on the title of your question, I assume you want to get this from the name of the queue you submitted the job to (o_cpu_128G in your example).  If that's the case, you should also find this available in the environment under the variable $LSB_QUEUE, so then you can display your queue name and your jobid in the xterm window title with:

```
echo -e "\033]2; Job ID: $LSB_JOBID Queue: $LSB_QUEUE \007"
```

Alternatively, you can try to determine the actual total/free memory on the host by parsing /proc/meminfo, or the output of a command like 'free -m'.

Comment: Thank you Sam,The $LSB_QUEUE did not work. It gives 'o_cpu'. It seems the qsub script is taking part of the queue name and takes it away. Unfortunately that's the part I want. Any way to find out the 128GB?

Comment: Oh I see, 'o_cpu' is the queue name according to LSF. The '_128G' part must trigger your wrapper script to select particular resource requirements perhaps.  Could you show me the output of 'bjobs -l <jobid>' for one of your jobs?